# Splitting an Array into Sub-Arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

### Problem

Given an **array of values** how can I split it into `sub-arrays` made of elements that are equal?

### Example

Given this array

```
let numbers = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4]
```

I want this output

```
[[1,1,1], [3, 3], [4]]
```

### What I am NOT looking for

A possible way of solving this would be creating some sort of index to indicate the occurrences of each element like this.

```
let indexes = [1:3, 3:2, 4:1]
```

And finally use the index to rebuild the output array.

```
let subsequences = indexes.sort { $0.0.0 < $0.1.0 }.reduce([Int]()) { (res, elm) -> [Int] in
    return res + [Int](count: elm.1, repeatedValue: elm.0)
}
```

However with this solution I am **losing** the original values. Of course in this case it's not a big problem (an `Int` value is still and `Int`even if recreated) but I would like to apply this solution to more complex data structures like this

```
struct Starship: Equatable {
    let name: String
    let warpSpeed: Int
}

func ==(left:Starship, right:Starship) -> Bool {
    return left.warpSpeed == right.warpSpeed
}
```

### Final considerations

The function I am looking for would be some kind of reverse of `flatten()`, infact

```
let subsequences: [[Int]] = [[1,1,1], [3, 3], [4]]
print(Array(subsequences.flatten())) // [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4]
```

I hope I made myself clear, let me know should you need further details.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
 // extract unique numbers using a set, then
 // map sub-arrays of the original arrays with a filter on each distinct number

 let numbers = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4]

 let numberGroups = Set(numbers).map{ value in return numbers.filter{$0==value} }

 print(numberGroups)
```

[EDIT] changed to use Set Initializer as suggested by Hamish

[EDIT2] Swift 4 added an initializer to Dictionary that will do this more efficiently:

```
 let numberGroups = Array(Dictionary(grouping:numbers){$0}.values)
```

For a list of objects to be grouped by one of their properties:

```
 let objectGroups = Array(Dictionary(grouping:objects){$0.property}.values)
```

Comment: Why use `reduce` to create the `Set`? You could just use the `Set` initialiser directly: `Set(numbers).map...`

Comment: You are right Hamish, I wasn't sure the set initializer would tolerate duplications but it does work and is much clearer.  However, since the OP intended to use internal properties of a Struct, either a .map() or the original reduce I had would eventually be needed.

Comment: @AlainT. I have an array of custom objects which i need to split up into sub arrays based off one property. I tried to modify your code slightly to achieve this but I got duplicates. My change looked like: let itemsGrouped = Set(items!).map{ value in return items!.filter{$0.custProp == value.custProp} } How might this need to change to get the desired outcome?

Comment: Set(items!.map{$0.custProp}).map{ value in return items!.filter{$0.custProp == value} } assuming custProp is hashable

Comment: In Swift 4 : Array(Dictionary(grouping:items){$0.custProp}.values)

Answer (score 5):

If you could use CocoaPods/Carthage/Swift Package Manager/etc. you could use packages like [oisdk/SwiftSequence](https://github.com/oisdk/SwiftSequence/#grouping) which provides the `group()` method:

```
numbers.lazy.group()
// should return a sequence that generates [1, 1, 1], [3, 3], [4].
```

or [UsrNameu1/TraverSwift](https://github.com/UsrNameu1/TraverSwift#groupby-function) which provides `groupBy`:

```
groupBy(SequenceOf(numbers), ==)
```

---

If you don't want to add external dependencies, you could always write an algorithm like:

```
func group<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element: Equatable>(seq: S) -> [[S.Generator.Element]] {
    var result: [[S.Generator.Element]] = []
    var current: [S.Generator.Element] = []
    for element in seq {
        if current.isEmpty || element == current[0] {
            current.append(element)
        } else {
            result.append(current)
            current = [element]
        }
    }
    result.append(current)
    return result
}

group(numbers)
// returns [[1, 1, 1], [3, 3], [4]].
```

Comment: I think adding a whole dependency just for using a simple grouping function is a bit too much. +1 for the algorithmic solution, that's the approach I used by implementing it into an `extension`

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that you have an unsorted array of items. You will need to sort the initial array then you will have something like this:
`[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4]`

After that you will initialize two arrays: one for storing arrays and another one to use it as a current array.

Loop through the initial array and:

- if the current value isn't different from the last one, push it to the current array
- otherwise push the current array to the first one then empty the current array.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning, using [Swift Algorithms](https://swift.org/blog/swift-algorithms/) this is now a one-liner:

```
import Algorithms
let numbers = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4]
let chunks: [[Int]] = numbers.chunked(by: ==).map { .init($0) }
print(chunks) // [[1, 1, 1], [3, 3], [4]]
```